# Android HTTP and cookies?

Tags: java, android, http

I'm working on a project where the API endpoints return an HTTP-only cookie that is used in further requests.  I'm not sure where this cookie saved nor how to remove it.  Where can I find this cookie for reuse and how can I remove it?

Answer (score 0):

The [CookieManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/CookieManager.html) manages the cookies, and makes it available for reuse, and has a method for removing a cookie.